HP laptop does not detect monitor
I have a new HP laptop and it will not detect a 2nd monitor.
Clicking Multiple Displays > Detect results in We didn't find another display
The graphics drivers are up to date
I've downloaded the AML Adrenalin Edition
The problem is not the monitor. It works connected to another laptop (Dell)
I've tried 2 monitors on the HP and neither are detected.
The problem is not the cables (I've tried both USB-C to HDMI and DP to HDMI). I've swapped cables several different ways and they work on the Dell with either of the aforementioned monitors.
Restarted any number of times
What else to try?
HP 17.3" Touchscreen Laptop
AMD Ryzen 5 7530U
Windows 11
The USB C port does not support external monitor:
1 USB Type-C® 5Gbps signaling rate (supports data transfer only and does not support charging or external monitors); 2 USB Type-A 5Gbps signaling rate; 1 AC smart pin; 1 HDMI 1.4b; 1 headphone/microphone combo
So we're down to the DP to HDMI connection
Did the following Windows updates:
2024-11 Cumulative Update Preview for Windows 11 Version 23H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5046732)
2024-11 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8.1 for Windows 11, version 23H2 for x64 (KB5048163)
The fix is to use an HDMI to HDMI cable. The monitor has both DP and HDMI inputs.

Please, add the model and specs of the monitor and laptop to the post. Do the Windows version too.
